# Having trouble using CASE to translate NULLs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, null, case

I"m using MySQL 5.5.37.  I have this in a select statement ...

```
select (CASE s.end_date WHEN NULL THEN NOW() ELSE s.end_date END)
```

however, what is being output when the column in quesiton is null is NULL. I would expect today's date to be output.  WHat is the proper way to translate a NULL column in a CASE statement to today's date?

Comment: Use WHEN 'IS NULL' or 'IS NOT NULL'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is close, but a bit off.  This is what you were trying to do:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.end_date IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE s.end_date END
FROM yourTable
```

But an easier and more concise way to handle possible `NULL` values in your `end_date` column would be to use the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(s.end_date, NOW())
FROM yourTable
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for `COALESCE`:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

In terms of your query, `COALESCE` will return `end_date` if it *isn't* `NULL`, and it will return `NOW()` if it *is* `NULL`.